# Error installing aircrack-ng from source, missing 'lnl-genl-3'

Tags: software-installation, make, aircrack-ng

`sudo apt-get install libnl-3-dev` is working, but now when I run `sudo make install`

```
lussy@lussy-HP-250-G1-Notebook-PC:~/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc4$ sudo make install
make -C src all make[1]: Entering directory /home/lussy/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc4/src'
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3  -msse2 -pthread -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -fstack-protector -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude  wpaclean.o osdep/radiotap/radiotap.o -o wpaclean -Losdep -losdep -lnl-genl-3 -lnl-3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnl-genl-3
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [wpaclean] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory/home/lussy/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc4/src' make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Why don't you simply install the version from the official universe repository? `sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng` is everything you need.

Comment: " install either libnl1 or libnl3." seems pretty straightforward?

Comment: Rinzwind, I already do it, but steel have the same problem... it's wired ....

Comment: @LussyKrasteva  You can [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/789436/edit) your question and ask your question their rather than asking that in the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

---

For compiling an application (aircrack-ng) that would be

```
sudo apt-get install libnl-3-dev
```

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libnl&searchon=names

---